# Angular js Sortable Drag And Drop

Tags: angularjs, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-dragdrop

Stuck in a problem where I have list of lists and i want to re-order the lists of list through drag and drop my model is

```
  {
  "selected": null,
  "lists": {
    "A": [
      {
        "data": "code"
      },
      {
        "data": "code enable"
      },
      {
        "data": "code disable"
      }
    ],
    "B": [
      {
        "data": "code"
      },
      {
        "data": "code enable"
      },
      {
        "data": "code disable"
      }
    ],
    "C": [
     {
        "data": "code"
      },
      {
        "data": "code decode"
      },
      {
        "data": "code decode"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now I want to re-order this model in such a way that if i drag the **lists C** to **lists A** it should replace the div new model will be

```
   {
  "selected": null,
  "lists": {
    "C": [
      {
        "data": "code"
      },
      {
        "data": "code decode"
      },
      {
        "data": "code decode"
      }
    ],
    "B": [
      {
        "data": "code"
      },
      {
        "data": "code enable"
      },
      {
        "data": "code disable"
      }
    ],
    "A": [
      {
        "data": "code"
      },
      {
        "data": "code enable"
      },
      {
        "data": "code disable"
      }
    ],
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
          <div ng-repeat="list in models.lists" class="col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-info" ng-repeat="data in lists">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">List {{data.data}}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**app.js**

```
 $scope.models = {
    selected: null,
    lists: {"A": [], "B": [],"C":[]
};

// Generate initial model
```

Comment: This isn't an answer, exactly, but for my drag and drop requirements I use https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-dnd It's MIT licensed open source, so there's really no restriction on use. Much greater flexibility and much easier than rolling your own.

Comment: looks good thanks for your suggestion